# Getting listbox items to display to another form

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

I'm still new here so please consider. My question is that I have two forms, (form1 and form2). In form1 there's a listbox with customers names on it. Now what i want is when the user clicks a name on the listbox, a new form (form2) pops up and displays the rest of the information of the customer (age,address,phone number) on the textboxes. When I click a name on the listbox it displays the rest of the info but only on that form, I can't get it to display on another form. I'm coding it using Visual studio, C#. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass information from form1 to form2 in one way or another.
If the data for customers is collected within a class, you can simply pass the object that corresponds to the selected index in the listbox.

For instance if your customer data in form1 is set up like this:

```
List<CustomerData> Customers { get; set; }
```

And each object in that list corresponds to its respective index in the listbox, then you would need a form2 constructor similar to this:

```
public form2(CustomerData customer){
  // set all form data here based on the customer
}
```

Potentially, if you asign the passed object in form2, you can manipulate the object within form2 and it will automatically update in form1 as well (assuming it is a class).

Then create your listbox click event method and open the form, passing the selected customer:

```
if(listbox.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
form2 f = new form2(Customers[listbox.SelectedIndex]);
f.Show();
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. A bit difficult to understand from your original question.

Comment: Sorry Sarkilas but i forgot to mention that the customer's data is located on a database. I dunno if that changes anything. Although I am having a bit difficult time understanding you answer but I really appreciate it.

Comment: It still shouldn't make a difference. Just pass logical data to the form2 and set the data there to show in the same manner you do so in form1.