# How to make listboxes remember data entered?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I'm using VB.Net and Visual Studio 2012.

The problem I have is the `Items` entered into the listbox disappears when the form is closed and reopened.

**The Scenario**

I'm creating a program that allows its users to create orders in a cafe. I have a menu system, when the application starts the user has a choice to open the newOrder form or the summary form.

When the user is in the newOrder form and has completed their order they press the button "save/ complete". When they press this button their order is added to a listbox on the side of the newOrder form.

But when i click the back to menu button and then return to the newOrder form the listbox is empty.

So my question is

- How do I make the application remember the information enter without using a database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vb listbox display in multiply forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474037/vb-listbox-display-in-multiply-forms)  Please do not ask the same question over and over.  See also: [Ask]

Comment: Sorry is that clearer @Plutonix

Comment: code sample? sounds like each time the button is clicked a new instance of the newOrder form is created and opened. if you use a module level variable to hold your form, then you can keep using the same instance until you want to create a new, fresh instance of the form.

Answer (score 0):

There would be many ways to do this but one fairly simple way is to use `My.Settings` and utilize the `System.Collections.Specialized.Stringcollection` type.

Comment: thanks for your response, could you explain how i would use this. With example code

Comment: Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx), give it a go and if you get stuck show what you have tried above and I will try and help from there, see also the link in the comment on the other question from Plutonix which shows another way to achieve it (probably the more professional way).

Comment: This is what i have done so far http://imgur.com/SA5xLFv, But i get an error message. @OSKM

Comment: Ok i think i fixed my previous problem but now i'm getting this error. [link](http://imgur.com/5vgctiG).  @OSKM

Comment: @IeuanWalker That error is self-explanatory... you can't add a string where a string-array is expected, isn't there an "Add" method instead of "AddRange" in that namespace?

Comment: @OSKM Thats seemed to fix it, but when i ran the code i got this error http://imgur.com/M1mxo27, i commented out this line and it was adding to the list box but not the My.Settings

Comment: Sorry for some reason I cannot access the imgur.com website - must be an error my end but I cant see what your error is.

Comment: @OSKM Sorry for the late reply, basically i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on this line of code 'My.Settings.MyListOrders.Add(order)'

Comment: what is `order`? if it is not a text string try `order.ToString` you do really need to post the code you are trying in your question above as it makes it much easier to help you.